# Association Rules in Rapid Miner

Tags: rapidminer

I wanted to ask this question in RapidMiner Community but after 2 days, still no answer.
It might be an easy question for you. I want to find a meaningful relation between a couple of column values. 
 the table is like this:

*SiteID*  , *Number Of 2MB users* ,   *Numberof 4MB users*, *Average 2MB speed Usage*, *Average 4MB speed Usage* , *Congestion Status*

It is clear that there is a relation between the number of users in each site and Average Usage of them and Congestion Status of the site.

but how to find it? a step by step guide would be helpful . 
So many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the operator `Correlation Matrix`. This finds how attributes are correlated and the second output of this operator is a matrix showing this.